# Override default "Recent Order" list view

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-object, list-view

I have been using a visualforce tab to override the default "Recent Order" list view for a custom object "orders__c"

Following is my code...

```
 <apex:page >
    <script type="text/javascript">
      parent.frames.location.replace("/a0q?fcf=00BK0000000yabc");                                          
 </script>
</apex:page>
```

I face problem everytime I migrate because of hardcoding the list-view id.

Is there a better or out of the box solution? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I also came across [this great hack](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hH5aAAE) by deepak. But then again the hardcoding issue arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't entirely agree with implementing JS as the solution, but independent of that, you can use a Hierarchy Custom Setting ([documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_setup.htm)) and merge in a value from it:

```
parent.frames.location.replace("{!$Setup.Order_Settings__c.Recently_Viewed__c}");
```

**EDIT**

You could also get the `Id` more programmatically by using `ApexPages.StandardSetController`. Take a look at the `getListViewOptions` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_getListViewOptions.htm), it gives you back a `List<SelectOption>`. Each represents a `List View` with `value=Id` and `label=Name`.

**Service**

The below is a rudimentary and generic attempt to pair an `sObjectType` with a `List View Name` and come up with its `Id` and also a corresponding `URL`.

```
public with sharing class ListViewServices
{
    public static String getId(SObjectType sObjectType, String name)
    {
        List<SObject> records = new List<SObject> { sObjectType.newSObject(); }
        ApexPages.StandardSetController controller =
            new ApexPages.StandardSetController(records);
        for (SelectOption listView : controller.getListViewOptions())
        {
            if (listView.getLabel() == name) return listView.getValue();
        }
        return '';
    }
    public static String getUrl(String sObjectType, String name)
    {
        if (String.isBlank(sObjectType) || String.isBlank(name)) return null;

        SObjectType schemaType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType);
        this.relativeBaseUrl = String.format('/{0}?fcf={1}', new List<String> {
            schemaType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix(),
            getId(schemaType, name)
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller**

Using the above service in a specific controller should be trivial.

```
public with sharing class ListViewController
{
    public static final String TYPE_PARAM = 'sobjecttype';
    public static final String NAME_PARAM = 'name';

    public String listViewUrl { get; private set; }
    public ListViewController()
    {
        this.listViewUrl = ListViewServices.getUrl(
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(TYPE_PARAM),
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(NAME_PARAM)
        );
    }
}
```

**VisualForce**

This would change your `Javascript` specifically to:

```
var listViewUrl = "{!URLENCODE(listViewUrl)}";
if (listViewUrl) parent.frames.location.replace(listViewUrl);
```

Comment: One thing that flew through my mind when I see "hard coded ID" issues is sticking them in custom settings instead.. which works when they are an Apex issue which you can't change on production orgs.. but you still have to "set/update" them., and seeing as you can just do this to VF pages anyway, putting the ID in a setting is no more simpler than the overhead of updating it on the page, so how does it help? (that said. functioning answer so you can have my vote!)

Comment: @SimonLawrence while changing a VF page in PROD is doable, the next time the VF page is deployed from  sandbox, the prod edit is smashed and has to be repeated as a post deployment task. Custom setting is done once in PROD and is unlikley to change value across repeated deployments

Comment: @adrian-larson Thanks for the tip. I have been using custom settings ever since your suggested. Sorry for late acceptance of your answer. Cheers :)